# Are files encrypted by BitLocker also encrypted after backup to OneDrive?

Tags: windows-10, onedrive, bitlocker, cloud-storage

Do files encrypted by BitLocker on Windows 10 Pro remain encrypted after being backed up to OneDrive or another cloud storage service?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

BitLocker is a full disk encryption feature, which means that your drive or volume is encrypted as a whole, not individual files. If you move or copy a file away from that encrypted drive, it is no longer encrypted.

So backing it up to OneDrive or any other place means it is no longer encrypted.

The cloud storage may use full disk encryption itself, but at least during transport the file is not encrypted.

There are other solutions if you need full end-to-end encryption for individual files.

Comment: How do I know if OneDrive  is full disk encryption or not?

Comment: We don't know, I don't think Microsoft is telling. There isn't really a point either. If they encrypt their drives, they also have the keys for it, not you. And because you upload your files unencrypted, if they want to they could always inspect your data before saving it (if they really want to)

Comment: This means that cloud storage is not reliable if files are not encrypted. Once cloud is breached for whatever reason, files will be exposed. So we are better use personal storage.

Answer (score 1):

Only if the cloud storage is also encrypted.
The reason is that after you boot up Windows (and enter your password), but before the backup happens the files are decrypted.

Compare it to copying the files to a USB drive.

Comment: What do you mean cloud storage is also encrypted? Let say that I backup encrypted files to one drive. I think the files on the one drive are also encrypted, right?

Comment: Any respectable cloud provider will encrypt their files, yes.

Comment: @MikaelKjær - You might want to go into more depth of what they do exactly.  While your files are encrypted, and can only be accessed if you share them, Dropbox could access your files for instance since they hold the keys to the encryption.  So could Microsoft and Google honestly.  *There are other cloud services that allow you to encrypt the file BEFORE you upload it to the provider.*

Answer (score 0):

You will want to use a cloud storage provider that supports End-To-End encryption like Spideroak or Sync.com as bit locker only encrypts files on your physical drive.